# storing videos in sqlite in android?

Tags: android, sqlite, video, navigation

I'm creating an application for android which is a 3D inside navigation system of a certain building the has a feature that allows the user to enter a location and destination (e.g lecture hall to office#xxx) and I've done the 3D view of the building in 3Ds max and stored as video file so I was wondering about how I can store all these videos in sqlite? and displaying them when the user search for them? I'm quite confused if I'm doing the right thing by storing them in a database or is there another easier way?

Comment: You should avoid storing binary data in SQL-databases. Use native files for this purpose instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't store the video in your sqlite database. Storing binary data in you database will lead to super bad performance. Common practice is to simply store the filepath to the video in your database. Then when you do a query, use the filepath to load the videos as needed.

Comment: what if I store the video in sdcard?..and then call it..will it still lead to bad performance? do you have any tutorial on how to store file path to the video in database? Thanx :)

Comment: If you store the video on the sdcard thats fine. Just don't directly store it in the database. Only store the file path in the database. As far as tutorials go, don't over think it. It's really simple, just store a varchar/string that is the file path. If you really need a tutorial, I'm sure google could come up with something for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to consider using a remote storage and stream the video in, when it's needed. You may also take a look at: [HTML5 video element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/video.html)