# How to save 3gp file(not path) in sqlite?

Tags: android

I want to save 3gp file in sqlite, not path of 3gp file. 
1. Is it possible to save 3gp file in sqlite ?
2. How to do it ?
3. If Yes, Which type of problem will generated after creating it ?

Revised:

I am able to save image file into sqlite using blob, For image,I am converting from "bitmap to byte array" for writing and converting from "byte array to bitmap" for reading. But for 3gp file I am not able to write and read it.

Comment: You may want to search for sqlite and BLOB.

Comment: yes, I am able to save image in blob but not 3gp

Comment: Can you explain what the problem is?

Comment: I want to save 3gp file in sqlite(Android), but not able to do it

Comment: why not as a BLOB? Any error?

Comment: Don't use blob if you don't have to...

Comment: Can you give a proper example how to implement it

Answer (score 3):

1. Try the Base64 Encoding/Decoding technique.
   get the input stream of the video and encode it into string by using Base64.

try this code:-

```
private String downloadVideo(String url)
    {
         String video = "";
         URL u = null;
         InputStream is = null;  

              try {
                       u = new URL(url);
                       is = u.openStream(); 
                       HttpURLConnection huc = (HttpURLConnection)u.openConnection();//to know the size of video

                   if(huc != null)
                   {
                       InputStream inputStream =  huc.getInputStream();
                       byte[] buff = new byte[8000];
                       int bytesRead = 0;

                       ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                       while((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buff)) != -1) {
                          bao.write(buff, 0, bytesRead);
                       }

                       byte[] data = bao.toByteArray();
                       video = Base64.encodeBytes(data);
                   }                     
              }catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
                     mue.printStackTrace();
              } catch (IOException ioe) {
                     ioe.printStackTrace();
             } finally {
                        try {                
                          if(is != null){
                            is.close();
                          }
                        }catch (IOException ioe) {

                        }

             }
              return video;
    }
```

Than you can store the string into database. while getting from database you can decode the string into input stream and get the real video.

2. try the below link here you will have the BLOB technique:-

http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/store-imagesfiles-database

But its not a good idea to store a video into database, it will increase the size of your database and the execution time of your query.

for more take a look:-

[storing videos in sqlite in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939312/storing-videos-in-sqlite-in-android)

[Store a video in a SQLite database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072884/store-a-video-in-a-sqlite-database)

Comment: Would you like to give some example, I have read your link but not able to get answer

Answer (score 0):

- **Is it possible to save 3gp file in sqlite ?**

  You got answer for that, BLOB.
- **How to do it ?**

  As bashu answered, using Base64 is a fine idea to do streaming of data. Using base64 you can conveniently save your data to your DB.
- **If Yes, Which type of problem will generated after creating it ?**

  This is the best question fragment that you asked. **YES , it will. Do not do it.** Instead, **keep the String values of filepath in DB and use them**.
  **Reason :**
  **1.** Unnecessarily, burdening the database.
  **2.** The cursor objects will give you exception, because when it comes to small devices, device memory is very important to keep in your memory.([Unless you are planning to keep images all together of size less than 1MB](http://www.sqlite.org/intern-v-extern-blob.html))

Comment: You shouldn't store a 3gp file into a database. You should instead save the URI to where the file is.

Comment: I know it, but I have to do it, please help

Comment: Anyways, if it is so important, then try to keep in such a way that a cursor calls out data less than 1MB. But this may lead to bad performance.

Comment: I am storing db file in sd card. Can you help me how to do it with proper example.

Comment: It's not about where you store the file but it's about the misuse of the cursor object. It's a check for not using huge data in db by sqlite.